# Can there be different private keys for the same public key in DSA?

Tags: dsa

From the Wikipedia page for DSA(Digital Signature Algorithm) we have the following private/public key generation:

1. Choose an integer x randomly from [1, q-1]
2. Compute y := g^x mod p
3. x is the private key, y is the public key

My question is: How are we sure that there does not exist z != x from [1, q-1], such that y = g^x mod p = g^z mod p and as a result, obtaining the same public key for different (z and x) private keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How are we sure that there does not exist z != x from [1, q-1], such that y = g^x mod p = g^z mod p and as a result, obtaining the same public key for different (z and x) private keys

We're sure about this because $g$ has order $q$, that is, $g^a \ne 1$ for any $a$ not a multiple of $q$ (and $g^q = 1$).  And, if $z, x$ had the same public key, that is, if $g^z = g^x$, then $g^{z-x} = 1$, and so $z-x$ must be a multiple of $q$.  Because we assume that $0 < z,x < q$, the only way this can be is if $z = x$, that is, they're the same private key.  QED.

Comment: How can we prove that if g^z = g^x then g^(z-x) = 1?

Comment: @ЛюбомирБорисов: multiply both sides by $g^{-x}$